# JPA serializing/deserializing nested autogenerated fields

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, repository

There is such a project in Spring-boot:

Model Page:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pages")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Page implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "color")
    private String color;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "page", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Note> note;

    // constructor, getters and setters
```

Model Note (One page can have many notes, notes.page_id is a foreign key to pages.id):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "notes")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Note implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "page_id")
    private Page page;

// constructor, getters and setters
```

Controller:

```
   public ResponseEntity<Object> createPage(@RequestBody Page page) {
       pageRepository.saveAndFlush(page);
       return new ResponseEntity("OK", HttpStatus.OK);
   }
```

When I make the Post request to the endpoint with the following Json request body

```
{
        "id": null,
        "color": "yellow",
        "note": [
            {
                "id": null,
                "title": "Java",
                "content": "Java is awesome",
                "page": null
            },
            {
                "id": null,
                "title": "Python",
                "content": "Python is good",
                "page": null
            }
        ]
    }
```

new records are made to DB, page id and note id are generated correctly but the field notes.page_id remains null.

Table `pages`:

```
id|color  |
1 |yellow |
```

Table `notes`:

```
id| content        |title |page_id|
1 | Java is awesome|Java  | null  |
2 | Python is good |Python| null  |
```

The question is: how can I provide notes.page_id with auto generated ids of the `pages` table?

Comment: Add the code for PageRepository. Also, have you tried making the note @Embeddable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle of JPA entities is actually quite simple.

You have a field in your JPA entity, which is mapped to a column in a database table.

What this field contains is written to the corresponding database column in the table.

Your `Node.page` field is the one mapped to the `note.page_id` column. 
And the value of the field is `null`. So what's written to the database column is `null`.

If you want to have a page ID in the column, you thus need to have a non-null `page` in this field. So your code needs to do

```
page.getNotes().forEach(note -> note.setPage(page))
```

As simple and logical as that.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your Note Class code as below

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="page_id", nullable=false)
private Page page;
```